# The bot does not join the voice channel

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

The bot refuses to connect to the voice channel, while there is no error in the console or anywhere, it seems to me that it just hangs on `voice_clients = await msg.author.voic.channel.connect()` please help to solve this.

```
import discord
import os
import asyncio
import youtube_dl
from discord import *

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
intents.voice_states = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

key = "MTA3ODY3OTcxOTIxMTQ0MjI5Nw.Gqtubx.SYqVZ7dwl8U3MpIK5mSIfXOSIi2qychJ0iddko"

voice_clients = {}

yt_dl_opts = {'format': 'bestaudio/best'}
ytdl = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(yt_dl_opts)

ffmpeg_options = {'options': "-vn"}  

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"GOTOVO KAPITAN{client.user}")


@client.event
async def on_massage(msg):
    if msg.content.startswith("?play"):
        try:
            voice_clients = await msg.author.voic.channel.connect() 
            voice_clients[voice_clients.guild.id] = voice_clients

            url = msg.content.split()[1]

            loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
            data = await loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: ytdl.extract_info(url, download=False) )

            song = data['url']
            player = discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(song, **ffmpeg_options, executable="C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe")

            voice_clients[msg.guild.id].play(player)

        except Exception as err:
            print(err)
        
    if msg.content.startswith("?pause"):
        try:
            voice_clients[msg.guild.id].pause()
        except Exception as err:
            print(err)

    if msg.content.startswith("?resume"):
        try:
            voice_clients[msg.guild.id].resume()
        except Exception as err:
            print(err)

    if msg.content.startswich("?stop"):
        try:
            voice_clients[msg.guild.id].stop()
            await voice_clients[msg.guild.id].disconnect()
        except Exception as err:
            print(err)

client.run(key)
```

I looked at quite a lot of similar situations on many forums, but I still did not understand why this happens and how to solve it, on the video from which I read this code, everything works out and I rewrote it several times. (I'm new to Python, so sorry if this is too easy a mistake)

Comment: I hope that key you have in your code is not a secret key

Comment: Yes, it was personal, but I noticed and changed it in time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you misspelled `on_massage` and I believe `msg.author.voic.channel` should be `msg.author.voice.channel`.

Comment: But what should the bot do once it gets massaged? :)

Comment: The code looks like it should connect to the voice channel correctly once the spellings are fixed, but using the variable name `voice_clients` twice could cause issues. Try changing the name of the variable that is declared inside on_message to `voice_client` and changing it in the next line as well to avoid an issue. Other than that, if the tutorial you watched mentioned adding the ffmpeg executable to `PATH`, the code looks alright.

Comment: If that was supposed to be a joke about a bot getting a massage, I totally missed it.

Comment: I'm sorry, couldn't help myself. Appreciate the thoroughness, though :)

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your statement correctly as voice_clints but I changed it in the next line to voice_client but what about this change that after this change the bot doesn't join ( I changed the line in the code from voic to voice)

Comment: Did you also change on_massage to on_message?

Comment: Yep, edited that too now,It worked, but this is the error that appears when entering the command, the bot joins but doesn't make any sounds

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\denys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 409, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Bot\Bot1\Voice_test.py", line 66, in on_message
    if msg.content.startswich("?stop"):
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'startswich'

Comment: Another spelling issue, it should be startswi**t**h not startswi**c**h

Comment: Fixed it, thank you very much. But the bot doesn't make any sounds at all, but now without an error.
2023-02-26 14:21:39 INFO     discord.voice_client Connecting to voice...
2023-02-26 14:21:39 INFO     discord.voice_client Starting voice handshake... (connection attempt 1)
2023-02-26 14:21:39 INFO     discord.voice_client Voice handshake complete. Endpoint found bucharest3770.discord.media
'VoiceClient' object does not support item assignment

Comment: Right now, does your code say
```
`voice_clients = await msg.author.voic.channel.connect()`
`voice_clients[voice_clients.guild.id] = voice_clients`
or
`voice_client = await msg.author.voic.channel.connect()`
`voice_clients[voice_clients.guild.id] = voice_client`
The second one is correct.
The error `does not support item assignment` refers to the voice_clients list. With the first chunk, you accidentally reassign voice_clients to be the specific client you're talking about, but the client cannot be item assigned. Dictionaries can, which is why distinction in variable names matters.

Comment: Okay, now what's the problem? (I want to cry already) 'Member' object has no attribute 'voic

Comment: My original answer mentioned that, it should be voice, not voic. You just misspelled it in multiple places.

Comment: Sorry fixed this bug but new problem       'dict' object has no attribute 'guild'

Comment: Remember this line? `voice_clients[voice_clients.guild.id] = voice_clients` this mentions `voice_clients` 3 times. You already changed the third instance to voice_client, but I failed to notice that the second one also should be changed to voice_client.

Comment: Should be `voice_clients[voice_client.guild.id] = voice_client`

Comment: Thanks a lot, fixed it. Here is the next error.         [youtube] jkHgqkSzYAs: Downloading webpage
[youtube] jkHgqkSzYAs: Downloading player 9419f2ea
ERROR: Unable to extract uploader id; please report this issue on https://yt-dl.org/bug . Make sure you are using the latest version; see  https://yt-dl.org/update  on how to update. Be sure to call youtube-dl with the --verbose flag and include its complete output.

Comment: Well.. go to the link and follow the instructions on updating it.